# Display the block and the inline words form right to left

Tags: html, css

I'd like to present the list from right to left,
here is the initial trial:

```html
<ul style="direction: rtl; ">
    <li >Casecading Style Sheet</li>
    <li>Hypertext Markup Language</li>
</ul>
```

How could I display it as

> ```
>                                                Sheet Style Casecading - 
>                                             Language Markup Hypertext-
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure CSS will not do the job, but little JS can help.

I take each string, split it and rejoin reversed. I use `display: none` for `ul` and then `document.getElementById('list').style.display = 'block';` so to avoid flickering when text is reversed.

#### Snippet

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var text = elements[i].innerHTML;
    var textReversed = text.split(' ').reverse().join(' ');
    elements[i].innerHTML = textReversed;
  }
  document.getElementById('list').style.display = 'block';
};
```

```css
ul {
  display: none;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>Casecading Style Sheet</li>
  <li>Hypertext Markup Language</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <ul style="direction: rtl; unicode-bidi: embed; ">
        <li >Casecading Style Sheet</li>
        <li>Hypertext Markup Language</li>
    </ul>
```

This should solve your issue.

Comment: It doesn't work. Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon 64-bit with Google Chrome - Version 67.0.3396.87 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: @AndrzejZiółek You'll have to use Javascript to reverse the characters of the String of each word, and then append it with this CSS.